# Can I keep crayfish and guppy fish together in a tank?

Tags: aquarium, fish, community-aquarium, compatibility, invertebrates

I have an aquarium and keep peaceful fish together like:

- angelfish;
- guppy;
- shark;
- *Hypostomus plecostomus*.

These are pictures of my fish in aquarium:

[image]

[image]

My fish are living together peacefully, **but I intend to buy a type of shrimp** and keep it with my fish in one tank. A type of shrimp that attracted my attention and I love to have it with my fish:

[image]

My question: can I have a lobster with my fish? Would it be peaceful with my **guppies**? Please help me, how can I do it? Is it possible to keep them in one tank together? I love this lobster type.

I think they are dangerous for my fish, which is concerning.

Comment: are you sure you mean lobsters and not crayfish.lobsters live in the ocean and crayfish in fresh water.crayfish eat fish so it is probably not a good idea to have them in the same tank.

Comment: @trondhansen I dont know exactly, just I added The picture is in my question.

Comment: you can take a look here to learn about them https://www.aquariumcarebasics.com/aquarium-crayfish/ i think you have to be careful in what fish you keep with them.

Answer (score 4):

There are many different types of aquarium crayfish, that have different levels of activity, aggression, size, and feeding habits, as well as different individual personalities, so its hard to say exactly if this would be ok or not.

As a general answer, I think you are correct in thinking they would be dangerous for your fish. Guppies are not great swimmers, and have long fins/tails that make them easier for other creatures to catch. It doesn't look like your tank has a lot of hiding places for them either, so that would likely cause a lot of stress and more risk from the crayfish.

Comment: what if i put some stuffs for hiding crayfish? then can i keep them together? I love this crayfish, what can i do??????

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi You need to do what is best for the fish involved - It's very difficult to know if it will work without putting them in together but it's a big risk and could go horribly wrong so it's best not to do it at all.

Comment: Hiding places for the crayfish would not help. If they want to attack/eat the fish they will find a way.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, crayfish would be an inappropriate fish to keep with your current selection. As an alternative to crayfish you might want to look at [giant fan shrimp (*Atya gabonensis*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atya_gabonensis). They look almost identical except these have fans not claws at the front. They don't grow as big as crayfish and they are not predatory. In fact, they're more likely to be attacked by the fish than the other way around.

[image: http://www.web.forumacvarist.ro/african-giant-filter-shrimp/]

You'll want to avoid keeping them with anything too large or aggressive but they might be a good alternative to crayfish.

Comment: but I cant find them in any aquarium stores

Comment: They're pretty common in shops in the UK - they should be able to order them in wherever you live.

Comment: But i am from iran.

Comment: Before I saw the recommendation to choose shrimp, rather than crayfish, in a community aquarium, this would have been my answer. Shrimp come in many beautiful colors, are generally docile, are great algae cleaners, and are interesting to watch. They can actually swim across the tank as quickly as most tropical fish. Just make sure they have plenty to eat, so they don't starve to death.